# After updating Android Studio, The emulator started to display the screen incorrectly

Tags: android

I updated Android Studio to the latest version and downloaded the latest packages using SDK Manager, and then when I tried to run the emulator it is displaying the screen like this
[image: emulator screen]

Also it is giving me this error:
Emulator: glTexImage2D: got err pre :( 0x506 internal 0x1906 format 0x1906 type 0x1401

However, when I run the emulator using software graphics the problem doesn't show but its very very slow, whereas when I run it using hardware graphics it is fast but the problem shows.

can anyone please help me to solve this problem and tell the reason of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue a few weeks ago.

I raised the issue on Google's Issue Tracker and it was related to a bug in the Intel Graphics Driver. I believe they've fixed it but I also found a work around in the mean time.

Check you have the latest graphics drivers, chipset etc, latest SDK tool and emulator version and reboot your PC. Ensure when you boot the emulator that you boot it as a cold boot as well.

If no luck then change the AVD settings to the following:

Set the renderer as  Angle (D3D11) and compatibilty to OpenGL ES 1.1/2.0 in the emulator settings.

You can do this doing the following steps:

1. Launch the emulator
2. Click the 3 dot menu on the toolbar on the emulator
3. Click Settings
4. Go to "Advanced"
5. Update render settings and the OpenGL API Level
6. Restart Emulator

You can find more info on the issue tracker at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109717070.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, 
the first solution didn't work, 
could you please tell me in detail how to set the renderer and the compatibility because I coudln't find out how

Comment: @WilliamSimon I've updated my answer to include the steps needed to change the settings on the emulator

Comment: it really worked!!, thank you very much for your help, you solved my problem

Comment: No problem, glad it helped

Comment: Is there any way to change this setting without the emulator actually being already launched?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, there may be a command line switch you can use but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools > AVD Manager > Virtual device configuration > Show advanced settings > Boot option > Cool boot

Then run again your project with that AVD. Close the session and set again Quick boot in Boot option.